# Rank nullity theorem proof

Tags: linear-algebra

So I'm watching a proof about the rank nullity theorem and it says this:

> Theorem. Let Ax=0 be a homogeneous system with n variables.
> Then the dimension of the nullspace is n-r(A).
> Proof: Denote k=n-r(A). k is the number of "degrees of freedom", so there are k $x_{i}$'s we can choose. Assume for simplicity that they are $x_{1}, x_{2} ... x_{k} $.

He then says this:

> A solution looks like this:
> $\begin{bmatrix} x_{1} \cr x_{2} \cr ...\cr x_{k}\cr a_{1}x_{1}+a_{2}x_{2} +... a_{k}x_{k}\cr b_{1}x_{1}+b_{2}x_{2} +... b_{k}x_{k}\cr ...\cr  c_{1}x_{1}+c_{2}x_{2} +... c_{k}x_{k}   \end{bmatrix}$

Now I'm honestly really confused because, well, the way he said it, that all the rows after the $x_{k}$th row are just linear combinations of the previous rows. But then I have a question, is this just a general solution to the equation $Ax = 0$, right? Why do you need linear combinations here? Like there must be some thing I'm not understanding, because all these rows are just going to be numbers when I solve for the vector, right? So would I not be able to represent it with just a scalar multiple of x1 for every single row? Like I really do not understand this. Could anyone help?

Comment: To me, the text in the quote does not sound like something a professional lecturer would say. Are you sure this an exact quote?

Comment: Also, your last paragraph seems to have some commas and fullstops missing. Would you please place them, so that it is easier to read and harder to misunderstand?

Comment: I tried to fix it https://youtu.be/407N5AXs1aM?t=521 and this is the video it's from, this just doesn't make sense to me like I don't understand him expressing the general solution like this.. k is just the amount of free variables right? The variables that can be any number we pick right? So yeah it makes sense you put those k free variables into the solution but then what's with the other variables being linear combinations? Aren't these all just numbers so they could just be expressed with a scalar times x1 or something

Comment: Try a simple example: Solve the "system" of linear equations $x+y+z=0$. Then $x,y$ can be freely chosen and the general solution is $(x,y,(-1)x+(-1)y)^{T}$.

Answer (score 1):

(A previous version of the answer, which misinterpreted the context, can be found in the edit history)

---

The statement you are confused about is important on its own and can be discussed separately from the rank-nullity theorem.

*Proposition*. A solution of a homogeneous linear system $\mathbf{Ax}=\mathbf{0}$ is of the form
$$\mathbf{x} = \left[\begin{array}{c}
x_{1}\\
\vdots\\
x_{k}\\
\alpha_{1}x_{1}+\dots+\alpha_{k}x_{k}\\
\vdots\\
\omega_{1}x_{1}+\dots+\omega_{k}x_{k}
\end{array}\right],$$
where $x_i$ are arbitrary numbers and all $\alpha_{i}, \dots,\omega_i$ are defined by $\mathbf{A}$.

This statement is probably proved or explained in [Lecture 17](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Dvi4UllI-Y&list=PLW3u28VuDAHJNrf3JCgT0GG_rjFVz0-j9&index=18). In a nut shell, by applying certain invertible row operations, you can transform any matrix $\mathbf{A}$ to the reduced-row-echelon form (RREF, also called "canonical" in these lectures). In this RREF, *the number of "leading 1's"* equals *the number of non-zero rows* equals *the number of basic columns*. Either of these numbers can be taken as a definition of the rank of a matrix, $r(\mathbf{A})$. The complete set of solutions to a linear system (aka the general solution) can be easily described by looking at the reduced-row-echelon form of the matrix (and the transformed right-hand-side, which is will be all zeros for a homogeneous system): some solution components are determined by the RREF and the right-hand side (there are $r(\mathbf{A})$ of them), the rest can be chosen arbitrarily (there are $n - r(\mathbf{A})$ of them). By reordering the vector components (together with the columns of the matrix), the general solution can be put in the above form, where $x_i, i=1\dots k$ are arbitrary.

This proposition is the most important to understand. It involves many non-trivial aspects, like the RREF, its existence, uniqueness, and why *any* solution is of this form. Afaic, some of them are not rigorously proved in these lectures, but even when taken on faith, they still deserve consideration.

Once you thoroughly understand the proposition, the rank-nullity theorem follows almost trivially. One may say that the proposition is much more involved and complex, whereas the rank-nullity theorem provides a high-level perspective on the image (aka the range) and null-space (aka the kernel) of a matrix as a linear operator.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. The $x_i$ in the OP are clearly scalars and they clearly have to be scalars.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Yes, I've just opened the video. The lecturer follows a different curriculum from what I am familiar with, in which one first proves statements about solutions of linear systems, and then proceeds to statements about matrices as linear operators. So in the OP's question and in the lectures, $x$ are scalars. I'll change the answer when I figure out how.

Comment: Yeah it would be nice to have a full answer maybe explaining the approach in the video because I honestly do not understand it.

Comment: @safelisdt Here you are.

Comment: Honestly though I still don't understand this like I know about rref but how are you expressing all these solutions using just random numbers? Like $x_{1}$ through $x_{k}$ are just the free variables right? They can be any possible number I want but then the rest of the variables $x_{k+1}, x_{k+2} $etc he just defines them using linear combinations of the the $x_{k}$'s right? Now of course this is possible if you have some numbers you can of course reach any number using a linear combination of them but you could also just reach any number by multiplying it by a scalar right?

Comment: Like why specifically linear combinations here? When you could simply have the solution be something like $(x_{1},x_{2} .. x_{k}, ax_{k+1}, bx_{k+1}, cx_{k+1})$ like this could also work right? I could reach any number using linear combinations of the solutions but also just a scalar multiply of one solution right?

Comment: @safelisdt Sorry, I am unable to understand your sentences, because they have inconsistent punctuation. Please ensure that each subject-predicate pair is clearly separated.